# Android's spinner text align right

Tags: android, spinner

I has a spinner contains 3 items:"English", "Simplified Chinese", "Traditional Chinese".
If I select "English", the spinner will show as below picture.
[image]
I means after select and show the selected one, but not all items list as below:
[image]
My layout.xml as below:

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_selector"
                    android:gravity="right" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to set the text align right.
But the width seems be set as the longest item.
And the text align left.
How can I modify it?

Comment: Can you post all your xml file ?

Comment: Create a custom adapter with a custom layout for your spinner.

Comment: I means show selected one, but not all items list.